# C# не число при инициализации корня

Tags: c#

Хочу инициализировать геометрическую фигуру, "трапеция". Консоль выводит не число, что делать?

```
public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Введите значение точек x1,y1: ");
        Trapezium.x1 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Trapezium.y1 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("Введите значение точек x2,y2: ");
        Trapezium.x2 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Trapezium.y2 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("Введите значение точек x3,y3: ");
        Trapezium.x3 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Trapezium.y3 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("Введите значение точек x4,y4: ");
        Trapezium.x4 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Trapezium.y4 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        
        Console.WriteLine($"\nРезультат: ");
        Trapezium.Lines();
        
        Console.Write($"Периметр трапеции: ");
        Trapezium.Perimetr();
        Trapezium.Heith();
        

    }
}
       
public class Trapezium 
{

    public static double x1, x2, x3, x4, y1, y2, y3, y4;

    public static double A, B, C, D;
    

    public static void Lines()
    {
        
        A = ((x2 - x1) * (x2 - x1) + (y2 - y1) * (y2 - y1));
        B = ((x3 - x2) * (x3 - x2) + (y3 - y2) * (y3 - y2));
        C = ((x4 - x3) * (x4 - x3) + (y4 - y3) * (y4 - y3));
        D = ((x1 - x4) * (x1 - x4) + (y1 - y4) * (y1 - y4));
        Console.WriteLine(A);
        Console.WriteLine(B);
        Console.WriteLine(C);
        Console.WriteLine(D);
        Console.WriteLine();
    }

    public static void Perimetr()
    {
       double perimetr = A + B + C + D;
        Console.WriteLine(perimetr);
    }

   
   

    public static void Heith()
    {
        double op = 2 * (A - B);

        double h = Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(C, 2) - Math.Pow(Math.Pow((A - B), 2) + Math.Pow(C, 2) - Math.Pow(D, 2)/op,2));
        double S = ((A + B) / 2) * h;
        Console.WriteLine(S);
    }

    

}
```

Comment: Ну протрассируйте ваш код, найдите, какая строка выдаёт не тот результат, который вы ожидаете.

Comment: Покажите вывод в консоль, неизвестно что вы вводите как исходные данные, а следовательно и непонятно, как воспроизвести вашу проблему. Моего уровня телепатии, чтобы понять в чем причина, к сожалению не хватило.

Comment: `Math.Sqrt` из отрицательного числа = `не число`. Проверяйте входные данные и формулу.

Comment: @aepot https://imgur.com/a/a8Wks9d

Comment: Добавьте текстом прямо в вопрос. И я уже сказал, почему так, вы пытаетесь вычислить квадратный корень из отрицательного числа.